# Parsing a date from a mongoDB with golang time.Now()

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am creating a date using Go via `time.Now()` and it store it in the mongoDB with no issue. The date looks like `2023-02-28T20:10:46.140+00:00`.

However when I try to retrieve it I get an error that reads:

```
{{"code":2, "message":"parsing time \"2023-02-28 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC\" as \"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\": cannot parse \" 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC\" as \"T\"", "details":[]}
```

It is coming from this piece of code.

```
createdAt, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, blog.CreatedAt.String())
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
updatedAt, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, blog.UpdatedAt.String())
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

tempBlog := &api.Blog{
    Id: blog.ID,
    CreatedAt: timestamppb.New(createdAt),
    UpdatedAt: timestamppb.New(updatedAt),
```

I found some useful documentation [here](https://gobyexample.com/time-formatting-parsing) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-go) and added the times parsed into Mongo manually, but I still run into this issue.

I have tried all of the [time formats](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) but it just results in a different error that is not able to parse.

Advice?

Comment: "The date looks like" --- unless it does not. Your error message says it's `2023-02-28 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC`

Comment: time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00", "2023-03-02T20:51:51.266+00:00")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store `time.Time` MongoDB will auto retrieve it for you. The retrieved time is on UTC, if you want change to your local timezone, use `time.Local()`.

```golang
package date_test

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

type Something struct {
    Name       string    `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    CreateTime time.Time `json:"createTime" bson:"createTime"`
}

func TestDate(t *testing.T) {
    raw := Something{Name: "demo", CreateTime: time.Now()}
    t.Logf("raw: %v", raw)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("URI")))
    require.NoError(t, err)
    collection := client.Database("test").Collection("demo")
    _, err = collection.InsertOne(ctx, raw)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    var res Something
    err = collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.D{{"name", raw.Name}}).Decode(&res)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    t.Logf("res: %v", res)
    t.Logf("local time: %v", res.CreateTime.Local())
}
```

Run the test code it will print something like this

```bash
$ URI="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/" go test -v ./date_test.go
=== RUN   TestDate
    date_test.go:21: raw: {demo 2023-03-07 10:26:22.433473 +0800 CST m=+0.009080292}
    date_test.go:32: res: {demo 2023-03-07 02:26:22.433 +0000 UTC}
    date_test.go:33: local time: 2023-03-07 10:26:22.433 +0800 CST
--- PASS: TestDate (0.01s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.912s
```

the mongo store the time like this

```js
> db.demo.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6406a0ce4cfff0411ca8d98b"),
    "name" : "demo",
    "createTime" : ISODate("2023-03-07T02:26:22.433Z")
}
```

source code is here https://gist.github.com/alex-x-crypto/14c15d4921f1ece2962302cce87c97a8

Answer (score 1):

The layout you are using for `time.parse` is `time.RFC3339` or `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00`.

I had a similar message when parsing time from Elastic, but was able to resolve it by removing the trailing `07:00`.  Try using a custom layout `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z` instead of RFC3339.

Comment: It still won't match their format: `2023-02-28 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC`

Comment: using `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z` or `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00` both did not work.

Answer (score 1):

your input format (2023-02-28 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC), as shown in your error message, can't be recognised by the time.parse function as it's not a RFC3339 format you called in the function.
I don't use much built in function but this 'format' function will give you what you need

```
inputs := "2023-02-28 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC"
extime, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", inputs)
fmt.Println("Time : ", extime)
```

result

```
Time :  2023-02-28 20:10:46.14 +0000 UTC
```

And if you need it back in RFC3339 to export use

```
fmt.Println("RFC3339 : ", extime.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"))
```

that will give you as a result

```
RFC3339 :  2023-02-28T20:10:46Z
```

Note that in UTC time (Zulu time) the RFC3339 don't ask to give the time modification just Z. If you had for example -0700 MST instead of +0000 UTC the result would have been

```
RFC3339 :  2023-02-28T20:10:46-07:00
```